# PHP - How to write the result of a for loop to a file

Tags: php, xampp, fopen, fwrite

I am trying to have a for loop run through each part of my array and print out a message saying "mason is spelled m a s o n". I understand how to write to a file and I understand using a for loop to print out each element in the array, but I do not understand how to get the data from the for loop output into a variable that I can put in my fwrite function. Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
$name = "mason";
$nameLetterArray = str_split($name);
$results = fopen("results.txt", "w");
fwrite($results, $forLoopOutput); //here forLoopOutput would be the "m a s o n" part
fclose($results);

$length = count($nameLetterArray);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
print $nameLetterArray[$i];
}
```

Comment: Simply move the fwrite to within the loop and the fclose to after the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already virtually written the code, there are only a few changes to make...

```
$name = "mason";
$nameLetterArray = str_split($name);
$results = fopen("results.txt", "w");
// Create output string to save multiple writes
$output = "";
$length = count($nameLetterArray);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
     //print $nameLetterArray[$i];
    $output .= $nameLetterArray[$i]." ";  // Add letter followed by a space
}
// Write output
fwrite($results, $name." is spelt ".$output); 
// Close file
fclose($results);
```

You could also use a `foreach()` in the loop instead

```
$name = "mason";
$nameLetterArray = str_split($name);
$results = fopen("results.txt", "w");
fwrite($results, $name." is spelt "); 
// Create output string to save multiple writes
$output = "";
foreach ($nameLetterArray as $nameLetter) {
     //print $nameLetterArray[$i];
    $output .= $nameLetter." ";  // Add letter followed by a space
}
// Write output
fwrite($results, $name." is spelt ".$output); 
// Close file
fclose($results);
```

Or (finally) you could use `implode()` instead of the loop...

```
$output = implode(" ", $nameLetterArray);
```

Comment: thank you, i knew a foreach could make it more concise but im more comfortable with the for, showing both def helped me learn

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple [fwrite()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) to a file, and at the end, you'll close the file pointer, like this:

```
<?php
$name = "mason";
$nameLetterArray = str_split($name);
$results = fopen("results.txt", "w");
fwrite($results, $forLoopOutput);

// Here you'll write each letter:
for ($i = 0; $i < count($nameLetterArray); $i++) {
  fwrite($results, $nameLetterArray[$i];
}

fclose($results);
?>
```